# C# method with multiple generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to build a generic method and four classes that implement `IDetail`. Each class has a collection of a classes that implement `ITaxes`. I want to build a generic method that will allow me to access the collection of each class.

Something like this:

```
public void UpdateCollection<T,I>(T Detail,Taxes TaxesList ) where T:IDetail where I:Itaxes
{
   foreach( Taxes  tax in TaxesList)
   {
       Detail.I.Add(tax);
   } 
}
```

I want to access the property of type `I` in type `T`. How can I do that? It is possible? 
Do I need to write one method for each class?

Comment: You can use reflection.

Comment: What do you mean by "the property of type I"? There could be multiple such properties, or none... you could use reflection to find all such properties, but it would be a very odd approach IMO.

Comment: Does `IDetail` implement an `I `property?

Comment: This is the usual situation where a bad data model leads to all sorts  of convoluted stuff

Comment: @Harrison No, each class has this property but it isn't part of IDetail implementation, because each one of them point to a diferent tables on my EF model

Comment: @HighCore Do you refer to write one method for each class ?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez no, I'm saying that if you have N different entity types that share the same properties (or different properties with different names which represent the same information or real-world concept) they should either be all derived from a base class, or all implementing a common interface, so that you don't have to resort to things like reflection for simple operations on these entities). The problem you have is related with the code you posted here, but with your data model, which does not expose a consistent set of properties and does not inherit from a base class.

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of using generics here? Would polymorphism and normal use of interfaces be sufficient? i.e. if all IDetails have an Itaxes property - defined in the interface - then generics might not be the way to go.

Comment: @GeorgePowell I'm usign generics due the property om each Detail, points to its own Taxes Property it mean: ClassA has a ClassA_Taxes, ClassB has a ClassB_Taxes and so on. But you give me another way. TKS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideally you'd modify your `IDetail` interface to include the list of `ITaxes` objects as a part of that interface.  You could use explicit interface implementation if you want the named property that is exposed publicly to have a different name for each detail.

If that isn't possible, or doesn't make sense for other reasons, then your best bet is probably to have this method accept a `Func<T, I>` parameter to this method.  The user can then provide a method to allow you to extract the required list from each `T` object:

```
public void UpdateCollection<T, I>(T Detail, Taxes TaxesList, Func<T, I> taxSelector)
    where T : IDetail
    where I : Itaxes
{
    I taxList = taxSelector(Detail);
    foreach (Taxes tax in TaxesList)
    {
        taxList.Add(tax);
    }
}
```

The caller than can use a lambda to define the appropriate property for that object.

Comment: I don't have much experience with ``Func``, please could you give me some ligth about the use of ``Func<T,I> taxSelector`` tks a lot for your help.

Comment: It's a delegate.  It represents a function that accepts a single parameter of type `T` and returns an object of type `I`.

Comment: @Srvy, very very tks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Create a third interface which exposes the commonality of what you seek. In partial classes (if generated) subscribe to the interface and then within the generic method accept only that interface and process accordingly.